# What could be optimal way of storing form response with version history or changelog when someone updates some data?

Tags: node.js, version-control, sequelize.js, versioning, database-versioning

## Problem Statement

I am trying to store a form response to a PostgreSQL table and maintain a **version history** along with timestamps **if someone updates any input** (just like what google docs offer, but for a form).

I am using NodeJS and Sequelize ORM in this project and didn't find anything Sequelize offers to solve this problem (did I missed?)

Is this anything natively available or I need implement custom?

## Solution 1

(but comes with another problem )

After doing some searches I found PostgreSQL offers a concept of [Temporal Tables](https://pgxn.org/dist/temporal_tables/) which uses **database trigger and save a dump of previous data before every INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE** fired.

But problem with this approach is for some minor update it will create copy of every column of that form response table.

## Solution 2

(might be good approach)

The most possible way I can think of is, when some inputs are updated in a form response before updating the row in database, **compare the request body with that form response row** which is already stored in database with some **JSON compare tools** like [deep-object-diff](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-object-diff)
 and save the changes only in a separate table with versioning and timestamps.

Might be a CPU intensive approach but what could be better?